# How to perform CRUD operation using Chrome extension storage API?

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I'm currently working on a Chrome extension and using the Chrome storage API (`chrome.storage.sync.set`) for saving my data but I'm having an issue to make it work.

The issue is that once I save an entry and wanted to save another the previous will be deleted.

- Popup.html

  ```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="data"></div>
    <input type="text" id="text"></input>
    <button id="set">Set</button>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
  </body>
  </html>`
  ```
- popup.js

  ```
  document.body.onload = function() {
    chrome.storage.sync.get("data", function(items) {
      if (!chrome.runtime.error) {
        console.log(items);
        document.getElementById("data").innerText = items.data;
      }
    });
  }

  document.getElementById("set").onclick = function() {
    var d = document.getElementById("text").value;
    chrome.storage.sync.set({ "data" : d }, function() {
      if (chrome.runtime.error) {
        console.log("Runtime error.");
      }
    });
    window.close();
  }
  ```

Is there a way to store tons of data without the previous ones deleted and is there a possibility to perform CRUD operation on a data I saved using the chrome storage API?

Comment: Your code overwrites whatever `data` was saved previously. If you want to append, use a different key name or simply read the value from storage first, append, save.

Comment: See [the documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage#property-sync): sync limit is 100kB, each object 8kB max.

Comment: I'm not getting you.

Comment: Can you please demonstrate it with a sample code?

Comment: op needs to read the official chrome storage docs before continuing this question.

Answer (score 3):

This is how you can append the value of a key in chrome.storage:

```
function storage_sync_append(val){
   // In get, {'data': []} sets the key value pair if it didn't exist; 
   // in this case the value is an empty Array
   chrome.storage.sync.get({'data': []}, result => {
       var temp = result.data;
       temp.push(val);
       chrome.storage.sync.set({ 'data': temp }, function() {
          if (chrome.runtime.error) {
            console.log("Runtime error.");
          }
       });
   });
}
```

In your code:

```
document.getElementById("set").onclick = function() {
  var d = document.getElementById("text").value;
  storage_sync_append(d);
  window.close();
}
```

As an aside, if you have more than one array to store with chrome.storage, the append function can be rewritten to work with any key:

```
function storage_sync_append(key, data){
//
   chrome.storage.sync.get({ [key] : []}, result => {
        var temp
        for(property in result)
            if(property == key)
                temp = result[property];

        temp.push(data);
        chrome.storage.sync.set({ [key] : temp }, function() {
           if (chrome.runtime.error) {
             console.log("Runtime error.");
           }
        });
   });
}
```